# Left Join to get previous record sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, left-join

So I am working on a system to manage best before checks in stores and when you're on a overview page of a check you see the following table

`Productgroup -> Productname    -> Barcode -> Checked -> Checked Time -> New best before -> Old best before`

I managed to gather all the data but Old best before using this query:

```
SELECT `thtchecksproducts`.*, productName, productGroup, productBarcode FROM `thtchecksproducts`
LEFT JOIN `products` ON thtchecksproducts.productID = products.productID 
WHERE `checkID`=:checkID ORDER BY checked DESC, productGroup ASC, productName ASC
```

now I need it to do another left join with the FROM table, thtchecksproducts. It needs to join on productID just like the last one but only with the last record that matches this query:

```
SELECT productID, max(id) FROM thtchecksproducts WHERE checkID IN (SELECT checkID FROM thtchecks WHERE userID=:userID AND closed=1 AND checkID IS NOT :checkID)
```

I came up with this:

```
SELECT s1.*, productName, productGroup, productBarcode FROM `thtchecksproducts` s1
LEFT JOIN `products` ON thtchecksproducts.productID = products.productID
LEFT JOIN thtchecksproducts s2 ON s1.productID = s2.productID
AND s1.id = (SELECT productID, max(id) FROM thtchecksproducts 
WHERE checkID IN (SELECT checkID FROM thtchecks WHERE userID=:userID AND closed=1 AND checkID IS NOT :checkID) AND productID = s1.productID)


WHERE `checkID`=:checkID ORDER BY checked DESC, productGroup ASC, productName ASC
```

Anyone who could help me getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Steffan:
You need to provide columns of all tables in your problem and business logic.
What rule describes "Old best before date"?  Is the "New Best Before date" always greater than sysdate?  In addition, is the query to determine the "Old best before date" always firing before a "New best before date" has been committed?

CK.